# A expressão match do PHP 8 é case sensitive?

Tags: php

O match é case sensitive?

```
$valor_de_retorno = match (expressao_sujeito) {
    expressao_condicional_unica => expressao_de_retorno,
    expressao_condicional1, expressao_condicional2 => expressao_de_retorno,
};
```

Comment: Sim e caso valor enviado seja diferente das expressões definidas e não tenha um valor default, será lançada a exception `UnhandledMatchError`.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta mostrando como fazer usar o match com qualquer função, o que poderá fazer o comportamento ser *case-insensitive*

Answer (score 5):

O `match` **não** faz comparações sobre "palavras", a comparação é sobre valores *idênticos*, ou seja, compara diferentes tipos de variáveis, não é exclusivo para strings, portanto não teria sentido ser *case-insensitive*.

Conforme a [**própria documentação**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php) diz:

> A expressão `match` ramifica a avaliação baseada em uma verificação de identidade de um valor. Semelhante a uma declaração `switch`, uma expressão `match` possui uma expressão sujeito que é comparada com múltiplas alternativas. Ao contrário da `switch`, ela irá avaliar para um valor assim como as expressões ternárias. Diferente do `switch`, a comparação é uma verificação de identidade (`===`) em vez de uma comparação de equalidade fraca (`==`).

Então `switch()` e `match()` irão comparar *strings* exatamente como são, o que difere é que o `match` compara valores estritamente (*idêntico*), como se fosse `$a === $b`, como é explicado na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

| Exemplo | Nome | Resultado |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `$a == $b` | Igual | Verdadeiro (`true`) se `$a` é igual a `$b`. |
| `$a === $b` | Idêntico | Verdadeiro (`true`) se `$a` é igual a `$b`, e eles são do mesmo tipo. |

Exemplo para notar como ocorre:

```php
<?php
$busca = 1;

switch ($busca) {
    case '1': # string
    case '2':
       $return_value = 'Encontrou';
       break;
    default:
       $return_value = 'NÃO encontrou';
}

echo "switch: {$return_value}\n";

$return_value = match ($busca) {
    '1' => 'Encontrou',
    '2' => 'Encontrou',
};

echo "match: {$return_value}\n";
```

Note que o `$busca` está usando um número inteiro e não uma string, no resultado o `switch` irá acusar que encontrou, enquanto o `match()` irá lançar a *expcetion* dizendo que não encontrou, resultado:

```
switch: Encontrou

Fatal error: Uncaught UnhandledMatchError: Unhandled match case 1 in C:\Users\inphinitphp\switchmatch.php:15
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\inphinitphp\switchmatch.php on line 15
```

Note que se definir *`default =>`* no `match()` não será emitido `UnhandledMatchError`, será semelhante a usar `default:` do `switch` ou `else {}` em `if()`s, exemplo:

```
$return_value = match ($busca) {
    '1' => 'Encontrou',
    default => 'NÃO encontrou',
};
```

### Case-insensitive com `match()`

Observe que no PHP existem recursos específicos para uso de *case-insenstive* de **strings**, como as funções:

- [strtolower](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)
- [mb_strtolower](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php)
- [strcasecmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php)
- [strncasecmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strncasecmp.php)
- [stristr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php)
- [stripos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

Se deseja buscar um valor, independente de ser *caixa alta* ou *caixa baixa*, em algo *semelhante a um dicionário*, você deverá implementar algo próprio usando as funções citadas acima e isso é possível fazer diretamente no `match` também, já que as chaves suportam tal comparação, um exemplo de `match` com `strcasecmp` que será *case-insenstive*:

```php
<?php

$busca = 'foobarbaz';

$return_value = match (0) {
    strcasecmp($busca, 'FooBarBaz') => 'Encontrou',
    strcasecmp($busca, 'Exemplo') => 'Encontrou',
    default => 'NÃO encontrou',
};

echo "match: {$return_value}\n";
```

Cada `strcasecmp(...)` retorna *int*, se for *zero* significa que o valor casou com o que foi definido no `match (0)` (expressão sujeito), você pode ajustar o valor definido no match que deve casar com os valores de cada *expressão condicional*.

**Nota:** o `match` só executa as funções dentro de cada *expressão condicional* na hora de comparar com a *expressão sujeito*, então se na primeira função retornar um valor que case, as próximas funções não serão executadas.